# Replace webrtc track of different kind without renegotiations

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, webrtc, mediadevices

I am working on a project in which we are using an audio call feature of WebRTC. Audio call works fine. On button click we need to enable share screen and replaceTracks with share screen track only, but replaceTrack web api replaces tracks of same kind, for example audio track can only be replaced with audio track or video track can only be replaced with video track. In my case, I am trying to achieve two things:
#1: I want to enable share screen while the audio track is on.
#2: If I can replace the audio track with share screen track appended in it without renegotiations.

Please check the code :-

```
 (async () => {
        try {
            await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(
                {
                    cursor: true
                }).then(stream => {
                    let videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                    var senders = peerConn.getSenders();
                    var sender = senders.find(function (s) {
                        return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
                    });
                    sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack);
                    videoTrack.onended = function () {
                        sender.replaceTrack(localStream.getTracks()[1]);
                    }
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('(async () =>: ' + err);
        }
    })();
```

In this s.track.kind is audio and videoTrack.kind is video.  sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack) gives error as it replace track of same kind

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what you are trying to achieveis not possible by design. You will need to renegotiate, i.e. create another offer and receive another answer.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Thank you for your response and it was helpful. Do I need to renegotiate again when
I stop screen sharing? Can you please throw some light on what is more optimized and efficient way from server memory usage point of view :-
 A. To start a video call from start and I use replaceTrack API without renegotiation.
 B. or to use audio call from the start and renegotiate three times (create another offer, receive another answer).